# PHP4 Valid code stopped working in PHP5?

Tags: php, arrays

Okay, so I have some code that worked fine in PHP4 but since upgrading to PHP5 it does not produce the results I want.

This is some code I have that displays some news posts in a nice 3-column format. It checks where the news post shall go and adds it to the corresponding array. Then it prints out the array.

Assume `$data` is an array containing news post content such as title, date and content.

```
// Add to columns.
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($data); $i++) {
    // Convert Date Format.
    $old_date = $data[$i]['post_date'];
    $middle = strtotime($old_date);
    $new_date = date('F d, Y', $middle);

    // Calculate amount of text to display.
    if(strlen($nh->getContents($data[$i]['post_content'])) > 100) {
        $post_content = $nh->getSnippet($data[$i]['post_content'], 500, TRUE);
        $post_content .= "...<br /><br /><a href=\"showNewsPost.php?post_id={$data[$i]['post_id']}\">Read more...</a>";
    } else $post_content = $nh->getContents($data[$i]['post_content']);

    // Setup content variable.
    $content = "
        <div class=\"content post\">
            <h1 class=\"title\"><a href=\"showNewsPost.php?post_id={$data[$i]['post_id']}\">{$data[$i]['post_title']}</a></h1>
            <h2 class=\"subtitle\">Posted on {$new_date}</h2>
            {$post_content}
        </div>
    ";

    // Add to appropriate column array.
    if(in_array($i, $leftIDs)) $left[] = $content;
    else if(in_array($i, $midIDs)) $mid[] = $content;
    else if(in_array($i, $rightIDs)) $right[] = $content;
}
```

The problem is where I have the `$content` variable and add it to an array stack. For some reason it is not adding it. When dumping `$content` it displays the news contents--so the data is being fetched properly from the `$data` array.

Printing out the `$left`, `$mid`, and `$right` arrays returns empty arrays. I've checked if the if-statements at the bottom were returning true--and they were. So why is my data not being added?

**EDIT**: The entirety of my code can be found [here](http://pastie.org/3430491)

*P.S.:* The reason for the arrays `xxID` is to figure out in which column the current news post will go. Then I just print everything out so that everything is displayed nicely.

Old: [old](http://i.imgur.com/jmhga.png)

New: [new](http://i.imgur.com/dlshF.png)

**UPDATE:** The lines that add the closing `</div>` to the end of the array: `$leftWrapper = sizeof($left) - 1; $left[$leftWrapper] = '</div>';` was overwriting the content that was added to array... odd because it worked in PHP4.... What a silly reason for not working. Thanks everyone for your input.

Comment: Please add `else echo "<!-- i not found in xxIDs: $i -->\n" at the end of the function and post results. (Ofcourse I guess $leftIDs, $midIDs and $rightIDs are borked)

Comment: @EugenRieck i added `else echo "<!-- i not found in xxIDs: $i -->\n";` to the end of my if-if-else statements but its not even displaying that after runtime

Comment: @lemonpole Looking at it, it appears fine. The only thing I could think of is something in that NewHandler class that is messing up. One way to find some stuff out is putting stuff like `echo 'here';` going from top to bottom and see where it stops echoing out 'here', at that point you know where it is breaking and can debug from there. And of course you can check your error logs too :)

Comment: So it doesn't display the comment **and** it doesn't add to $[left|mid|right] **but** $content is set correctly immediately before the if-else if ?

Comment: @EugenRieck yes... $content is set correctly before the if-else if

Comment: This means, that **none** of the branches in the last if-else if-else if-else conctruct is taken, which seems quite impossible to me with a working PHP installation.

Comment: but when i change `$left[] = $content` with `echo 'here'` it does echo the string...

Comment: I'VE FIXED THE PROBLEM! For some odd reason the last bit that adds the closing '</div>' to the last element in the array was causing the entire array to be overwritten? View my post for more details...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bet is you are a victim of http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals being defaulted to off in PHP5, as it should be since it can be security risk leaving them on. I would verify that, if that is true the solution can be complicated or easy, depending if you want security or not. In order to verify, you will need to either post a bit more code, or test on your server.

Comment: I tried enabling it to verify if that was the problem but still nothing. Enabling it involves setting `register_globals = Off` to `register_globals = On` in the PHP.ini file right?

Comment: @lemonpole Right. If that did not work, we really do need to see a bit more code, and you should check the error logs, to see if anything is flaring up. As far as the snippet you showed, that seems to be fine, nothing should be different across php versions. So yea. Unless there is something wrong with the `$nh` class.

Comment: Why why why why why would you intentionally turn `register_globals` on...for your own safety I would recommend recoding instead of enabling it.

Comment: @Cyclone, he turned it on to verify if that was the issue. I do not think he intends to leave it on.

Comment: @BradFJacobs I've uploaded my code to pastie--view my edit above for link.